# Как создать конструктор статей Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

Дано:
Задача создать конструктор статей который позволит зарегистрированным на сайте людям создавать информационные статьи на какие либо темы(если совсем простым языком - создать аналог создавалки вопросов на СтекОверфлоу с возможностью вставки картинки / подчеркивания текста / цитат но имеющий другое назначение)
Т.е. есть ли какие то готовые решения? Как это можно оформить в плане сущности для БД ? Используется java , Spring , Hibernate , JSP

Answer (score 0):

Короче говоря вот та хотелка о которой я говорил называется "rich textarea" и готовых решений много